# Notepad++ masschange using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have issues to perform a mass change in a huge logfile.
Except the filesize which is causing issues to Notepad++ I have a problem to use more than 10 parameters for replacement, up to 9 its working fine.

I need to change numerical values in a file where these values are located within quotation marks and with leading and ending comma: `."123,456,789,012.999",`

I used this exp to find and replace the format to:
`,123456789012.999,`  (so that there are no quotation marks and no comma within the num.value)

The exp used to find is:

```
([,])(["])([0-9]+)([,])([0-9]+)([,])([0-9]+)([,])([0-9]+)([\.])([0-9]+)(["])([,])
```

and the exp to replace is:

```
\1\3\5\7\9\10\11\13
```

The problem is parameters `\11` `\13` are not working (the chars eg `.999` as in the example will not appear in the changed values).

So now the question is - is there any limit for parameters?
It seems for me as its not working above 10.  For shorter num.values where I need to use only up to 9 parameters the string for serach and replacement works fine, for the example above the search works but not the replacement, the end of the changed value gets corrupted.

Also, it came to my mind that instead of using Notepad++ I could maybe change the logfile on the unix server directly, howerver I had issues to build the correct perl syntax. Anyone who could help with that maybe?

Comment: I'm so confused. Can you just state what you want to do in one or two sentences?

Comment: Change

."123,456,789,012.999",


to:

.123456789012.999,

However theare are commas separating all values within the files so simple removal of comma is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a little play myself, it looks like back-references \11-\99 are invalid in notepad++ (which is not that surprising, since this is commonly omitted from regex languages.) However, there are several things you can do to improve that regular expression, in order to make this work.

Firstly, you should consider using less groups, or alternatively non-capture groups. Did you really need to store 13 variables in that regex, in order to do the replacement? Clearly not, since you're not even using half of them!

To put it simply, you could just remove some brackets from the regex:

```
[,]["]([0-9]+)[,]([0-9]+)[,]([0-9]+)[,]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)["][,]
```

And replace with:

```
,\1\2\3\4.\5,
```

...But that's not all! Why are you using square brackets to say "match anything inside", if there's only one thing inside?? We can get rid of these, too:

```
,"([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)",
```

(Note I added a "\" before the ".", so that it matches a literal "." rather than "anything".)

Also, although this isn't a big deal, you can use "\d" instead of "[0-9]".

This makes your final, optimised regex:

```
,"(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\.(\d+)",
```

And replace with:

```
,\1\2\3\4.\5,
```

Comment: I could take this answer further if you like. For example, perhaps you need to not always match numbers of that exact length; maybe some numbers contain more/less than 3 commas??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the regex groups has limitations, but you could use lookarounds to save 2 groups, you could also merge some groups in your example. But first, let's get ride of some useless character classes

```
(\.)(")([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+)(")(,)
```

We could merge those groups:

```
(\.)(")([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+)(")(,)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We get:

```
(\.)(")([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(")(,)
```

Let's add lookarounds:

```
(?<=\.)(")([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(")(?=,)
```

The replacement would be `\2\4\6\8`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed length of digits at all times, its fairly simple to do what you have done. Even though your expression is poorly written, it does the job. If this is the case, look at Tom Lords answer.

I played around with it a little bit myself, and I would probably use two expressions - makes it much easier. If you have to do it in one, this would work, but be pretty unsafe:

`(?:"|(\d+),)|(\.\d+)"(?=,)` replace by `\1\2`

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/zL3fY5

Comment: Whilst I agree a more flexible answer like this is probably better than the one I gave (although I'd have to look at the actual text file to be sure). There is one problem with this, though: You are replacing '"' and ',' with ' '.

Comment: @TomLord: atleast `"`, yeah. Guess I could add a lookahead to be sure it isnt replaced incorrectly.